# Get reference to cached version of container using createJS

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, createjs, easeljs

I have a card game in which I create all 52 cards once and cache them one by one.

I want be able to display same card (e.g. King of Spades) multiple times as efficiently as possible. Currently I'm cloning the existing cards whenever I need to display multiple instances of it.

Is there a way to either clone a cached card, so that the clone will have the same cache or get a reference to bitmap (cached) version of my card?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can clone the card using `card.clone()`, which will share the same `cacheCanvas` as the originally cloned item. Additionally, you can create bitmaps using another cacheCanvas as the source:

```
var bmp = new createjs.Bitmap(otherItem.cacheCanvas);
```

Have you considered using the SpriteSheetBuilder class? Creating a single SpriteSheet behind the scenes, and then generating Sprites using it would give you performance gains, since only a single bitmap would be used behind the scenes.

http://www.createjs.com/docs/easeljs/classes/SpriteSheetBuilder.html

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions Lanny, I'll look into SpriteSheetBuilder. Using another item's cacheCanvas to generate bitmaps was exactly what I was looking for.